# How to uninstall kata containers?

Tags: docker, containers, kata-containers

There are multiple ways of installing kata containers, given in the docs. However, is there one provided to uninstall kata?

I want to remove everything that kata installed on my computer, so I can start the installation fresh.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it; dpkg --list, then sudo apt-get --purge remove **item

Though I'm not  sure if this would work / remove everything. If anyone can comment on this that would be appreciated. Thanks!